# How to customize bottom of Android's AlertDialog

Tags: android

Is it possible to cutomize only the bottom of the alert dialog? I would like to set a different background color for the part where the Yes/No buttons are displayed without changing the rest of the window.

[image: Android's AlertDialog]

Comment: You can create a custom layout for the alert dialog. Check [How to create a custom alert dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Comment: @SripadRaj thanx, the given link seems to contain the answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the complete layout of button then try to create custom layout for alert dialog

or if you just want to change the color of the buttons then try below code

```
AlertDialog.Builder aDB = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewApplication.this);
aDB.setCancelable(false).setNegativeButton("Yes",new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          //Do something
     }
});
AlertDialog alertDialog = aDB.create();
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).
setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Note : Write the upper code after the dialog.show();